# Delete dead host from Cloudera

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I'm trying to delete host from cluster in Cloudera Manager.
Host is dead an unavailable. When I click 'delete' for the selected host I get message:

> BlockquoteThe following 1 host(s) cannot be deleted because they are not completely decommissioned or have roles with dependent services

Unfortunately I can't decommission this host either. Decommissioning of HDFS runs forever (over a night) at step

> Waiting for Decommissioning to finish.

In 'Actions' menu for this host 'Stop Roles on Hosts' is inactive.
'Start Roles on Hosts' fails and does not make 'Stop Roles on Host' active.
'Remove Hosts from Cluster' does not work as it first tries to decommission the host.

Any ideas how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem on Cloudera Manager 5.11 ... after googling around the procedure that worked was going inside each ROLE and removing the dead host from the instances of that role ... then on the "ALL HOSTS" view the dead node become "commissioned" and it was possibile to delete it

Answer (score 0):

For deleting a node from cluster, we need to stop the agent running on the nodes using service cloudera-scm-agent stop and then try to delete from cloudera manager.